# Given a matrix A of order $n$, then how many possible order of minor's exists and how to calculate it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let A be a square matrix of order 3 over $R$ then minor of $a_{11}$ is determinant of the square submatrix of order 2 which is the result of leaving $1st$ row and $1st$ column, like that we calculate minors of all elements of matrix A, so there are $9$ minors of order $2$, similarly minor of order $3$ in A is the determinant of A, also does there are minor of order $1$ in $A$?

My questions are "for an n by n matrix"  what are the possible order minors and how to calculate those?

Comment: Are you asking how many minors of, say, order $m$, exist in an $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: yes, also what are the possibilities order of minor of a square matrix A?

Answer (score 1):

For a $3\times 3$ matrix, if you remove 0 rows and columns, you have a 3rd order minor. If you remove 1 row and column, you get a 2nd order minor. If you start with an $n\times n$ matrix and you want a minor of order $m$, then you remove $n-m$ rows and columns. The number of rows you can remove is between 0 and $n-1$ (you can't just get rid of the whole matrix), so $$0\leq n-m\leq n-1 \implies 1\leq m\leq n$$ Those are the possible minor orders.

Each minor of order $m$ is specified by choosing $n-m$ rows out of $n$ rows, $n-m$ columns out of $n$ columns, and removing them. So the number of such minors is $$^n\mathrm{C}_{n-m}\cdot^n\mathrm{C}_{n-m} = (^n\mathrm{C}_m)^2$$